# Synchronous sequence using RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm struggling on how to express the following with RxJava. Let's imagine I have a stream of packets list that I want to transmit on a network :

```
PublishSubject<List<Packet>> packetsSubject = ...;
```

And I have the following transmission function:

```
public Observable<Status> transmit(Packet p) {...}
```

I want to transmit each packet of a list as long as the returned status of the packet is `Status.OK`. In other words, if the transmission of the n-th packet is NOK, then, the n-th+1 packet should not be send.

Also, if an error is detected:

- an error should be displayed with the index of the packet in the list
- the transfer of the next list of packet should start

Thank you for reading me

Comment: Did you try to use the `concat` operator? For the error handling does the new list have any relation with the old one?

Comment: The two list have nothing in common, I'm getting a list of packets by slicing a request payload. How would the concat operator fit in the picture?

Comment: I think with `concat` the requests happen in the same order they are in the list. If one fails then you don't try the next item.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `flatMap()` operator to convert lists to observable entries. Use the `zipWith()` operator to pair up each list entry with the index of the packet in the individual list. `flatMap()` again to transmit and get the resulting status. Turn a `NOK` into a throwable, and terminate the interior observer chain. When using the `flatMap()` operator, adding the final parameter of `1` makes the mapping occur one a time, so there is no overlapping of requests in this observer chain.

```
packetsSubject
      .flatMap( listOfPackets -> Observable.from( listOfPackets )
            .zipWith( Observable.range( 1, LARGE_NUMBER ), ( p, i ) -> new Pair<>( p, i ) )
            .flatMap( pair -> transmits( pair.getFirst() )
                    .flatMap( status -> status.equals( "OK" )
                            ? Observable.empty()
                            : Observable.error( new IllegalStateException() ) )
                    .doOnError( error -> System.out.println( "Error at index " + pair.getSecond() ) )
                    .onErrorResumeNext( Observable.empty() ), 1 ) )
    .subscribe();
```

While I am uncomfortable with the final interior steps of mapping the `NOK` to an error, logging it, and then remapping the result back, there is a reason for it. The processing of `listOfPackets` has to terminate either when all the packets have been processed or when a `Status.NOK` is seen; turning `Status.NOK` into an error indicator accomplishes this. However, we only want the processing of an individual list to terminate, and not the entire observable.